# Node Promises with webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, promise, webdriver-io

I am trying to run selenium web scraping and failing. Please look at the code snippet.

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var client = webdriverio
              .remote({ 
                desiredCapabilities: { 
                 browserName:'chrome' 
                } 
              });
module.exports = function(some_url) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    client
     .init()
     .newWindow(some_url)
     .getHTML('html')
     .then(function(html) {
       var some_data = someFactory(html); // do some data scraping
       Promise
        .all(
         some_data
          .some_array
          .map(function (data) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
             client
              .newWindow(data.other_link)
              .getHTML('html')
              .then(function (html) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html); // do some more scraping
                resolve(html);
              })
              .end();
            });
          })
        )
        .then(function (data) {
          // execution never comes here while I get html in 
          // the mapped function
          resolve(some_data, data);
        });
     ).end();
});
```

This above execution never completes. It never comes out of the inner block.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is broken and very messy. You are mixing deferreds and promises and does some really weird promise resolutions as well as trying to resolve multiple values. Please reformat your code so it's runnable, and specify what you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: @DanielB I have removed deferred. I want to scrape some values from a url and some other values from the url's it carries. The final output should carry information from the parent url as well as its children.

Comment: looks ok to me.

Comment: @LynHeadley But doesn't works :-(

Comment: I would recommend to have a catch function at the end of the queue so you know what's going on. Also if you want to open a url use `url` not `newWindow`.